# Why is is_readable() lying?

Tags: php, windows, permissions, command-line-interface

I loop through all files on my system, then do this check before the hash_file() call, since it kept giving me errors such as `hash_file(): Read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied` or `Failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable:`:

```
if (is_readable($path))
    hash_file($path, ...);
```

It still does it. `is_readable()` clearly doesn't check if it is readable at all, or else it wouldn't keep spitting out those errors even with this check.

How do I actually make sure that the file path in question can be read and won't result in any errors?

Comment: The results of `is_readable()` are cached, you could get these sorts of errors if the file is frequently changing. See [`clearstatcache()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky I just tried the same script with clearstatcache() before every tick. Same exact thing happens.

Comment: What's in `$path`?

Comment: @AlexHowansky A path to a file.

Comment: Paste an example. Is it actually a real local file? Is in in a system temp dir? Is it a URI? Is it on a removable device?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I told you I'm looping through all files on my system. It's just any random file on a local disk. Why does it matter? It doesn't. I want to make sure it won't cause an issue when I read it.

Comment: Are you opening the file in read mode?

Answer (score 0):

At first try to replace the is_readable function with the following:

```
function f_is_readable($path) {
    $f=@fopen($path,"r");   
    if ( $f===false ) {
        return false;
    }
    fclose($f);
    return true;
}
```

If it works as you expected, we can assume that is_readable function is buggy for your PHP version.